# Using Magic in Vim? (Regex in matchstr function)

Tags: vim

I am having a hard time understanding this "magic" thing in Vim.

Currently I am making a very simple regex search to get last list of numbers in a string:

```
    for file in files
        echo file
        let versionNum = matchstr(file, '(\d+)(?!.*\d)')
    end for
```

Something like that in above. Basically if a string is: xxx.xxx.xxx.x1234 I should only parse out 1234.

However, I am having hard time using a regex expression in matchstr and a bit of google searching weren't enough to make me fully understand what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `\v` at the start of your pattern to explicitly require to work in magic mode.

Also, the syntax you're using isn't supported by vim. While not perfect, I'd use: `\v.*\D\zs\d+|^\d+`, or more simply: `\v\d+\ze\D*$`.