# Why won't this regex work in SublimeText when it does in Vim?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have this regex

```
^\([^\t]*\)\t\([^\t]*\)\t\([^\t]*\)$
```

which is supposed to match

1. beginning of the line
2. a capture of all letter until a Tab
3. a capture of all letter until a Tab
4. a capture of all letter until a Tab
5. the EOL

In Vim, this works fine:
[image: correct regex capture]

But in Sublime it will not match.  Why?

Comment: Interesting ratio of upvotes to views - i wonder if this is a common issue that many don't think to search about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim regex is [rather specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604617/why-does-vim-have-its-own-regex-syntax) and differs from the PCRE regex engine expression syntax that Sublime Text 3 uses.

In Sublime Text 3, you can write the pattern you used in Vim as

```
^([^\t\r\n]*)\t([^\t\r\n]*)\t([^\t\r\n]*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j5Jjdp/1)

In short, `(...)` should be used to form a capturing group, and you need to add `\r\n` to disallow a negated character class to match across lines (in Vim, `[^.]*` won't match a line break, but it will in Sublime Text 3).

Note that `(...)` (and not `\(...\)`) can also be used as a capturing group in Vim, but you need to use [very magic mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308769/using-magic-in-vim-regex-in-matchstr-function) to use that syntax.